# Better, compact code for these WHILE? :) (vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Thank you for your answer.

This code is working 100%, It change the background color of slides div, base on slide index (f).
so slides from 0-19 are gray, 20-39 are red... etc.

But this looks like a noob coder, (which I am!) :)

can you think of a better way? compact, or this is the best we can do!! :)

Thanks!!!!

```
var f = 0;
while(f < 20) {
  slides[f].classList.add("gray");
  f++
}
f = 20
while(f < 40) { 
  slides[f].classList.add("red");
  f++            
}
f = 40
while(f < 60){ 
  slides[f].classList.add("yellow");
  f++            
}
f = 60
while(f < 80){ 
  slides[f].classList.add("green");
  f++            
}
f = 80
while(f < 100){ 
  slides[f].classList.add("blue");
  f++            
}
```

Comment: In case you’ve only been looking at JavaScript so far, note that CSS has `:nth-child(n+20)`, so if your slides are siblings you can do it all in CSS.

Comment: What you are asking for is a code review and you should be asking such questions on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colours=['gray','red','yellow','green','blue'];
for (f=0;f<100;f++)
   slides[f].classList.add(colours[Math.floor(f/20)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might notice that your variable "f" goes from 0 to 100 and increases by one each time you add a color, so a better option would be to use a for loop:

```
var color = "";
for(let f = 0; f < 100; f++) {
    if(f < 20) color = "grey";
    else if(f < 40) color = "red";
    else if(f < 60) color = "yellow";
    else if(f < 80) color = "green";
    else if(f < 100) color = "blue";
    slides[f].classList.add(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a loop of loops:

```
const colors = ["gray", "red", "yellow", "green", "blue"];
for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<20; j++) {
    slides[i*20 + j].classList.add(colors[i]);
  }
}
```